# Unfolding XML with XSLT possible?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

This is an XML document I would like to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<batchResponse>
  <searchResponse>
    <searchResultEntry dn="uid=Massan Jill">
      <attr name="cn">
        <value>Massan, Jill</value>
      </attr>
      <attr name="userAccount">
        <value>ABC1234567</value>
        <value>DEF1234567</value>
      </attr>
    </searchResultEntry>
  </searchResponse>
</batchResponse>
```

This is the xslt I created for Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <entry>
      <xsl:for-each select="batchResponse/searchResponse/searchResultEntry">
        <xsl:if test="@dn!='' and contains(@dn, 'uid=')">                 
          <import>      
            <cn>
              <xsl:value-of select="attr[@name='cn']/value"/>
            </cn>
            <userAccount>
              <xsl:value-of select="attr[@name='userAccount']/value"/>
            </userAccount>
          </import>    
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the transformed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <import>
      <cn>Massan, Jill</cn>
      <userAccount>ABC1234567</userAccount>
   </import>
</entry>
```

My Problem is, that the original XML data contains several values for "userAccount" and that the transformed XML should reflect this by unfolding such data to multiple import-entries like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <import>
      <cn>Massan, Jill</cn>
      <userAccount>ABC1234567</userAccount>
   </import>
   <import>
     <cn>Massan, Jill</cn>
     <userAccount>DEF1234567</userAccount>
   </import>
</entry>
```

Is this even possible with xslt and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xsl:for-each` to select each "user account" entry, and then create an `import` record for each one of this

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <entry>
      <xsl:for-each select="batchResponse/searchResponse/searchResultEntry">
        <xsl:if test="@dn!='' and contains(@dn, 'uid=')">                 
          <xsl:for-each select="attr[@name='userAccount']/value">
          <import>      
            <cn>
              <xsl:value-of select="../../attr[@name='cn']/value"/>
            </cn>
            <userAccount>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </userAccount>
          </import>    
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the expression `<xsl:value-of select="../../attr[@name='cn']/value"/>` to get the user name. This is because you are positioned on the `value` element, so you need to go back up the hierarchy to get the user name (`..` means get the parent of the current node).

Actually, you can combine the two `xsl:for-each` statements, and the `xsl:if` into one, to simplify things. Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <entry>
      <xsl:for-each select="batchResponse/searchResponse/searchResultEntry[@dn!='' and contains(@dn, 'uid=')]/attr[@name='userAccount']/value">
      <import>      
        <cn>
          <xsl:value-of select="../../attr[@name='cn']/value"/>
        </cn>
        <userAccount>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </userAccount>
      </import>    
      </xsl:for-each>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `@dn!='' and contains(@dn, 'uid=')` can be shortened to  `contains(@dn, 'uid=')`.

Comment: Thank you Tim! This really helps a lot (and your solution works, btw.). Also, thank you for the hint regarding the shortening of the condition Michael.